# Need to split water line behind refrigerator to add an espresso machine

Tags: plumbing, water

Just a quick explanation of what I'm trying to do. I'm not a plumber by any means, but I'd like to try to get this done on my own.

I have an espresso machine on the counter next to my fridge. I want to plumb it in, so I bought an Everpure ESO6 filter:

[image: ESO6 Everpure Cartridge]

Also the Everpure QL3B Filter Head:

[image: Everpure QL3B Filter Head]

This will go under my cabinet, so I'll be drilling a hole on the side with a spade bit in which the braided hoses for both the espresso machine and to the water source will go through.

Here's how everything looks connected:

[image: Current setup of filter manifold with braided hoses and tee]

The problem I'm having now is how I get the tee connected to the water source. Here is my water source, which currently has the refrigerator connected to it (1/4"):

[image: Water source behind refrigerator]

**My question is:** How should I tee this? I bought a tee that's 1/4" outside diameter (OD), but the problem (as I was told by a Home Depot employee) is that all ends are male. But couldn't I just connect a 1/4" braided hose to the water line, then into the tee, then plug the line to the filter and the line to the fridge, and that would be it?

I'm also wondering if I actually need a pressure regulator. My manual says if line pressure exceeds 5 bars (~70psi) then I'd need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, it looks kind of tight in there.

can you fit the tee with the cross-piece going into the spigot and then use a flexible line with an elbow on the end to connect to the side of the tee, connect the other flexible line to the end of the tee.

else turn the main water off, drain the system, and raise the spigot on an extender the screw the tee on.

Answer (score 1):

Pressure regulator would depend on your incoming water pressure. Ask the city if it is city water. As for plumbing the tee in, you can use an length of hose needed to get the water to the fridge and espresso maker.

Answer (score 0):

> Couldn't I just connect a 1/4" braided hose to the water line, then
>   into the tee, then plug the line to the filter and the line to the
>   fridge, and that would be it?

YES.

> I'm also wondering if I actually need a pressure regulator.

Probably not, but you can reduce the flow with a control valve and this should also effectively reduce your pressure as well. Although it might interfere with how fast water fills the unit.